# python - pandas dataframe print column if value = 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Have this data in panda dataframe:

```
animal      tall    swim        jump  
frog          0        1            1
toad          1        0            0
tadpole       0        0            1
```

Would like this output:

```
frog swim
frog jump
toad tall
tadpole jump
```

Any builtin function for this?

Comment: This should get you close: `df.set_index('animal').dot(df.columns[1:] + ',').str.strip(',')`

Comment: @coldspeed it is close, frog       swim,jump is one one line though

Comment: @jezrael can u reopen ? idxmax will only return 1 result per line, we want all that have 1 in a line

Comment: You are right, need something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), filter `1` and create `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
df1 = df.set_index('animal').stack()
s = df1[df1==1]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':s.index.get_level_values(0),
                    'b':s.index.get_level_values(1)})
print (df2)
         a     b
0     frog  swim
1     frog  jump
2     toad  tall
3  tadpole  jump
```

Another solution is use [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html):

```
df2 = s.index.to_frame(index=False)
df2.columns = ['a','b']
print (df2)
         a     b
0     frog  swim
1     frog  jump
2     toad  tall
3  tadpole  jump
```

Different solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and filtering by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df2 = (df.melt('animal', var_name='val')
         .query('value == 1')
         .sort_values('animal')
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         .drop('value', axis=1))
```